# In vba fill Array from QUery then insert the data into table

Tags: mysql, arrays, ms-access, vba

So I want to insert the result of a query into an array then I will loop over the array to insert new rows to a new table.
Here is the code I've done:

```
Public cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Public db As DAO.Database

Public Sub SUD_Main()
    Set db = Access.Application.CurrentDb
    Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection

     Refreash    
End Sub

Private Sub Refreash()
Dim DataArr() As String
    Dim p As Variant
    Dim sql As String
    Dim XDATA As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim RDS As DAO.Recordset
    Set RDS = db.OpenRecordset("tbl_dets")

    sql = "SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM Types_tbl WHERE NAME LIKE 'Rob%'"
    XDATA.Open sql, cnn, adOpenStatic

    '''
    '' HERE I WANT TO FILL DataArr FROM XDATA
    '''
    DataArr = XDATA.GetRows

    XDATA.Close
    For Each p In DataArr
        sql = "SELECT DISTINCT TID FROM Types_tbl WHERE NAME ='" & p & "'"
        XDATA .Open sql, cnn, adOpenStatic

       Do Until XDATA.EOF
       DoEvents 
           '''Inserting new records to tbl_dets
           RDS.AddNew
           RDS!Name = p
           RDS!TID= XDATA!TID
           RDS.Update
           XDATA.MoveNext
       Loop
       XDATA.Close
    Next
End Sub
```

So what I am missing? I thing that the error is in the Array but didn't know how to fix it.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Type mismatch on   `DataArr = XDATA.GetRows`

Comment: XDATA.GetRows -----
Copies multiple records from a Recordset object into a two-dimensional array and you are  trying to add the output into string. I guess this may be the issue

Comment: I there another way to add the records to the dynamic Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mostly valid, but you are making some mistakes.
`GetRows` returns a multi-dimensional array with rownumbers and fields. As such, you can't fit it into a string. You need to use an array of type variant.

```
Private Sub Refreash()
    Dim DataArr() As Variant
    Dim p As Variant
    Dim sql As String
    Dim XDATA As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim RDS As DAO.Recordset
    Set RDS = db.OpenRecordset("tbl_dets")

    sql = "SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM Types_tbl WHERE NAME LIKE 'Rob%'"
    XDATA.Open sql, cnn, adOpenStatic

    '''
    '' HERE I WANT TO FILL DataArr FROM XDATA
    '''
    'Make sure XData fetches all records
    XData.MoveLast
    XData.MoveFirst
    DataArr = XDATA.GetRows

    XDATA.Close
    For Each p In PATTs
        sql = "SELECT DISTINCT TID FROM Types_tbl WHERE NAME ='" & p & "'"
        XDATA .Open sql, cnn, adOpenStatic

       Do Until XDATA.EOF
       DoEvents 
           '''Inserting new records to tbl_dets
           RDS.AddNew
           RDS!Name = p
           RDS!TID= XDATA!TID
           RDS.Update
           XDATA.MoveNext
       Loop
       XDATA.Close
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that there are some things I still don't understand about this sub, possibly because it is not finished, such as it not using DataArr anywhere after setting it and the use of both ADO and DAO (I'd prefer to only do DAO in this case).

Comment: I miss wrote PATTs instead of DataArr so instead of `For Each p In PATTs` it suppose to be `For Each p In DataArr `